# Razor view engine - exception when calling Any Function

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to convert an existing ASPX page to cshtml format.

The original ASPX looks something like this:

```
  <%
    if (!Model.ObjectList.Any())
    {

      %>
      <tr>
          <td>No data found</td>
      </tr>
      <%
     }
```

The equivalent Razor version looks like this:

```
@if (!Model.ObjectList.Any())
 {
 <tr>
   <td>No data found</td>
 </tr>
 }
```

While the original syntax works just fine, the equivalent fails with the following message

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'Any'

I was wondering
**a)** why this is happening and
**b)** how to resolve this issue. I've added a reference to the System.LINQ namespace in my CSHTML file but to no avail.

Any help is much appreciated,

JP

Comment: Have you included an assembly reference for System.Core?

Comment: Sure he did, because `System.Web.Mvc` depends on `System.Core` and the site wouldn't even run.

Comment: @JP, I've tested your scenario and was unable to reproduce the error.

Comment: I notice you said a reference to "System.LINQ" when it should be "System.Linq" - just a thought.

Comment: I tend to use the web.config page/namespaces area to add any imports that are missing in my views. Maybe you could try adding the `System.Linq` reference there and see if that helps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for their answers. This turned out to be an ID 10 T....

Essentially I neglected to strongly type my view. I was using

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<dynamic>
```

instead of using

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<MyViewModel>
```

Using the correct type fixed the issue.
Thanks again,
JP

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the correct namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this too:

```
@if (Model.ObjectList.Count == 0)
 {
 <tr>
   <td>No data found</td>
 </tr>
 }
```